# MySQL statement-based replication and stored procedure

Tags: mysql, replication

When you have a MySQL statement-based replication and you create a stored procedure that modify some rows (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE commands...), What is really replicated on the slave when you call this procedure on the master ? The CALL himself or the commands (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE...) inside the procedure ?

For example, create such a procedure:

```
delimiter |

CREATE PROCEDURE myproc ()
      BEGIN

        DELETE FROM mytable LIMIT 1;

      END |

delimiter ;
```

Then call on the master:

```
master> CALL myproc();
```

=> does it replicates "CALL myproc()" or "DELETE FROM mytable LIMIT 1" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no, your CALL is not replicated

You can take a look into the FAQ starting from [B.4.22](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#qandaitem-B-4-1-22) and the [Binary Logging of Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-logging.html)

**B.4.23: Are stored procedures and functions created on a master server replicated to a slave?**

> Yes, creation of stored procedures and functions carried out through
>   normal DDL statements on a master server are replicated to a slave, so
>   the objects will exist on both servers. ALTER and DROP statements for
>   stored procedures and functions are also replicated.

**B.4.24: How are actions that take place inside stored procedures and functions replicated?**

> MySQL records each DML event that occurs in a stored procedure and
>   replicates those individual actions to a slave server. The actual
>   calls made to execute stored procedures are not replicated.
>
> Stored functions that change data are logged as function invocations,
>   not as the DML events that occur inside each function.

Comment: +1, but as the docs say, for stored functions there COULD be a `call`.

Comment: @ShlomiNoach, I can't find where the slave "for *stored functions* there COULD be a `call`"

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't a quote. This is the quote: "Stored functions that change data are logged as function invocations, not as the DML events that occur inside each function.".

Comment: So in the case of a function that modifies data, what replicates is the CALL to the function, not the function itself. But if same function does not modify data, then the CALL does not replicate.